# Как при нажатии на кнопку в компоненте перейти на другой компонент?

Tags: vue.js

У меня есть условие при выполнение которого должно перекидывать на другой компонент.

```
v-if="otvet === 'Регистрация завершена'"
```

Не нужно отправлять мне ссылки на документации, я уже много чего перепробывал, ничего не помогает.

```
<template>
  <form>
    <h2>Регистрация</h2>
    <p>
      <label for="name">Ваше имя:</label>
      <input type="text" id="login" v-model="login">
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="password">Ваш пароль:</label>
      <input type="text" id="password" v-model="password">
    </p>
    <button type="button" name="button" @click="register">Зарегестрироваться</button>
    <p> {{ otvet }}</p>
    <button v-if="otvet === 'Регистрация завершена'" @click="'Home'">join chat</button>
  </form>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios';
import Home from '../components/Home.vue'

export default {
  components: {
    Home
  },
  data() {
    return {
      otvet: null,
      login: '',
      password: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    register() {
      axios
      .get('/reg',{
        params:{
          login: this.login,
          password: this.password
        }})
      .then(responce => this.otvet = responce.data)
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

Кнопки join chat быть не должно, при выполнения условия, получения ответа от сервера, он автоматически должен открывать компонент Home

Comment: На другой компонент или другой роут? Покажите полный код

Comment: @RavenTheX обновил

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так не надо делать. Компоненты должны быть независимы.
При получении ответа надо передавать главному приложению событие:

```
.then((responce) => {
  this.otvet = responce.data;
  this.$root.$emit('user-registered');
})
```

А приложение уже пусть это событие обрабатывает:

```
methods: {
  openHome: function () {
    this.homeOpened = true;
  }
},
mounted: function () {
  this.$on('user-registered', this.openHome);
}
```

и в шаблоне:

```
<home v-if="homeOpened"></home>
```

Comment: можете расписать по-подробнее как передавать главному приложению событие, подстраиваясь под мой код? @ВикторКараев

Comment: Уточнил в ответе.